# multiple sets of cookies for iframes / embed elements / logins

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, session-cookies

as long as we needed just two different logins on the same webpage we just used the incognito tab feature: did the job just well. Now we are at the point where we need three of them; the incognito method no couldn't help because even different incognito windows share the same cookies.

Therefore we thought it would be nice to use iframes / embed the website(s) on what ever technique will make the catch...

does work; the saved cookies in the browser aren't accessed, the CORS problem could be fixed with the chrome extension "Ignore X-Frame headers" or the x-frame-bypass: https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass

But how on earth, could I assign to the first element the set of cookies_1 and to the second cookies_2?

The logins are permanent, the sessions cookie will never expire and for security reasons: on the page it self you cant do anything, you see only the assignments that aren't fulfilled: nothing more.

The cookies could be easy extracted from the browser by simply signing in regular, but you cant login twice because the site finds the session cookie and the other authentication related cookies and doesn't give you to opportunity to open it twice.

Maybe you say: you're completely wrong, take this way: I'm fine. What I need is a solution that runs out of the browser or on a server / xampp environment.

Comment: Add something to the URL of the iframe-d pages, so that you can differentiate them based on that on the server side. Could be a GET parameter `login=1`, then based on that your application would know that it would need to look for `cookie_1` now. It will still get the _other_ cookies submitted to it as well though. If you don't want that, then it would probably make more sense, to put that info at the beginning of the URL path, using URL rewriting - `/1/login`, `/2/login`. Then you could also limit the "visibility" of the cookies you are setting to the paths `/1/`, `/2/`, etc.

Comment: @CBroe i cant edit anything on the server of the webpage: it is not mine, but I have to deal with different logins to the same site. 

For example: you are trying to use youtube in iframes with different accounts. 

The cookies and the structure of them are fixed and cant be edited I "just" need a way to parse them to the iframes / embed objects what ever.